# SFML TCP socket doesn't wait for data

Tags: c++, network-programming, sfml

Code is here

```
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char mode = *argv[1];

    if(mode == (char) "-s") {
        sf::Packet recMessage;

        sf::TcpListener tcpListener;

        sf::TcpSocket inClient;

        tcpListener.accept(inClient);

        inClient.receive(recMessage);

        cout << recMessage << endl;
    }
}
```

When ran with -s i'm expecting the program not to close until it receives data but when I run the program it closes.

Comment: Hint: `mode == (char) "-s"` is not correct, and won't do what you expect it to. Use [`std::strtmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp) to compare strings. Or, you know, use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed mode to a std::string and took out the char castings

The if statements run now if I run into any more trouble I'll make another question